# Force:NavigateToURL application event issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community-builder, napili

I am building a lightning component to be used in a Customer Service template within a customer community.

I am using following code snippet, to redirect to a knowledge article page, where target url is something like **/article/article-unique-url**

```
var forceUrlEvent = $A.get('e.force:navigateToURL');

forceUrlEvent.setParams({
   url: targetUrl,
   isredirect: false
});

forceUrlEvent.fire();
```

What it internally does on redirection, that it embeds article version id in the URL and URL become something like this:

> /article/ka1000000000abc/article-unique-url

It was all working till Friday and suddenly stopped working. Same code is still functional in another sandbox.

**As a workaround**, I am able to resolve the issue by directly updating "window.location.href" value. But I wanted to understand the nature of the root cause.

Comment: Have you activated Lightning Knowledge ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, it was working perviously, so yes knowledge is enabled.

Comment: I mean, if you go to Setup/Knowledge Settings, is "Enable Lightning Knowledge" checked ?

Comment: When I said everything was working fine, I actually meant that I can see articles in the community and all their details.

Answer (score 2):

Summer '17 changed the way that Communities handles this. You used to be able to point to the SEO link or the ID and it'd find the right path- but now it's a lot more strict.

Use the navigateToSObject event, or the fully qualified path which is `'/article/' + article.Id + '/' + article.UrlName` in conjunction with navigateToURL.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty this is useful only if it is happening in your sandbox that switched to summer 17 on friday

Comment: @ItaiShmida Community templates are automatically upgraded the moment they're released post Winter '16.

Comment: so he actually has a summer 17 community template in his prod?

Comment: @ItaiShmida- look at his first sentence- "I am building a lightning component to be used in a Customer Service template within a customer community."- it clearly implies that he's _building_ a component _to be used_ in a community. Please point out where he said "prod" in the original answer.

Comment: Yeah it is on Summer 17 and I reckon, that's why it stopped working. I will try the navigateToSObject event, to see if it meets the redirection thing. Otherwise I have already done the full URL workaround.